# Vuelidate, v-for and child componented

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuelidate

I have a form that is built on a child / parent structure, with the core form details in the child.

The following all works, in so far as the data data updates and the parent correctly handle the data on submit.

However we would like to add basic validation to the child components, so that the parent is unable to be submitted if the `required` data in any of the children is absent

I'm assuming that I need a `validation` object on the parent with a `$each` but beyond that can't figure out how to pass the model between parent and child

**Parent component**

```
<b-form>
  <child-item
    v-for="(item, index) in form.children"
    :key="index"
    :item-ref="index"
    :item-year.sync="item.year"
    :item-selection.sync="item.selection"
  />
</b-form>

data: {
  return () {
    form: {
      children: []
    },
    pristine: {
      children: []
    },
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
<b-form-row>
  <b-form-group
    label="Year"
    :label-for="`form-year-${ItemRef}`"
  >
  <b-form-input
    :id="`form-year-${ItemRef}`"
    v-model="year"
  />
</b-form-group>
<b-form-group
  label="Selection"
  :label-for="`form-selection-${ItemRef}`"
>
  <b-form-input
    :id="`form-selection-${ItemRef}`"
    v-model="selection"
  />
</b-form-group>
...
props: {
  ItemRef: Number,
  ItemYear: String,
  ItemSelection: String,
},
computed: {
  selection: {
    get () {
      return this.ItemSelection
    },
    set (newData) {
      this.$emit('update:item-seletion', newData)
    }
  },
  year: {
    get () {
      return this.ItemYear
    },
    set (newData) {
      this.$emit('update:item-year', newData)
    }
  }
}
```